# What is the cause of this drastically different simulation behavior with slight variation in capacitor values?

Tags: stability, tools, development-tools, positive-feedback

This site uses Circuit Lab's schematic and simulation tool, for which I am grateful. Recently, I was attempting to modify a circuit present in [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/472706/268467) answer to a question.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fM0sbA.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I kept getting rather strange results:

[image: Output when C1 is 5uF]

However, if I change the value of C1 from 5uF to 5.6uF, I get this result:

[image: Output when C1 is 5.6uF]

In each case, I used a step time of 0.01 seconds.

Would I be correct in concluding that Circuit Lab uses non-polarized capacitors by default when the value of the capacitor is standard, but polarized capacitors by default when the value of the capacitor is "odd"? Is there some other explanation for this behavior?

Edit: Some new data points:

Mattman944 suggested that the simulation would work better if I decreased the step size. I tested with a 0.001 sec step, and the running to the rails was not visible within 10 seconds. This suggests that the mathematical limitations of simulating the circuit may be at least partly responsible for the running to the rails behavior.

Bruce Abbot noticed that the + and - inputs of the second op amp are reversed from the original circuit. I tested with the inputs corrected, and the simulation did not show running to the rails within 10 seconds. This suggests that the circuit itself may be at least partly responsible for the running to the rails behavior. (I actually was a bit surprised that the circuit in this question gives as stable an triangle wave with the 5.6uF capacitor as it does.)

I am convinced that my original conjecture that the problem lay in two different capacitor models depending on whether the capacitor was a standard or "odd" size, is wrong. I am inclined to believe that:

a) the circuit as I drew it, is essentially unstable (as a triangle wave generator).

b) a finer step in the simulation allows a longer time before the instability becomes apparent.

c) I just happened "get lucky" that the instability was apparent after 5 cycles with the 5uF capacitor, and not apparent with the 5.6uF capacitor within 10 seconds.

Comment: + and - inputs on the 2nd (integrator) op amp should be swapped over?

Comment: You are right. However, I am still curious about the fact that changing the capacitor value by 12% changes how the simulator behaves by over 100%. I will test the circuit with the + and - inputs swapped.

Comment: OK. Tested, and the running to the rails disappears when the op amp inputs are swapped. Can I conclude that that the simulation is accurate, and the circuit I have is actually unstable, and I just happened to get lucky with the 5.6uF choice?

Comment: Yes, I think you just got 'lucky'. Seems the simulation acts unrealistically until the integrator + input exceeds some very small threshold voltage, then it flips into doing what it should (locking up in one direction or the other). I tried this circuit in LTspice with "start external DC supply voltages at 0V" and it immediately locked up no matter what capacitance I used, but with that option turned off both op amps got stuck 'on a knife edge' at exactly zero volts. Adding 1 picovolt of noise caused it to 'flip' into normal operation after 23ms.

Comment: Great data points. Would you like to write up an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> a) the circuit as I drew it, is essentially unstable (as a triangle
> wave generator).

Correct. With both op amps acting as amplifiers with positive feedback the result is a [bistable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flip-flop_(electronics)) circuit that wants to lock up in one direction or the other. To work properly the integrator + and - inputs should be swapped around to produce negative feedback through the capacitor.

> b) a finer step in the simulation allows a longer time before the
> instability becomes apparent.

It seems so.

> c) I just happened "get lucky" that the instability was apparent after
> 5 cycles with the 5uF capacitor, and not apparent with the 5.6uF
> capacitor within 10 seconds.

Yes. the overall positive feedback should cause it to immediately lock up to one supply voltage or the other, but a simulation may be too 'perfect' to show the instability.

When I tried your circuit in [LTspice](https://www.analog.com/en/design-center/design-tools-and-calculators/ltspice-simulator.html) both op amps stuck 'on a knife edge' at exactly zero volts, until I added a tiny bit of noise into the circuit to push it 'off the knife edge' and lock up. If I turned on the option "Start all DC supply voltages at 0V" it acted correctly.

Answer (score 1):

No, it has nothing to do with cap values. It will work better with a smaller time step.

When the time step isn't small enough, errors will accumulate faster. The triangle wave is very slowly drifting negative, at some point it will hit the limit of the opamp.

Comment: Interesting. I decreased the step time from 0.01 sec to 0.001 sec and the problem disappeared, at least for the first 10 seconds. But why does the  5.6uF capacitor not give this problem?

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy If you decrease the frequency of the circuit then the time step doesn't need to be a small.

Comment: I appreciate the insights you brought to the problem. Thank you. It may have been obvious to you that the circuit itself was prone to lock up. However, I have awarded the answer to Bruce Abbott who pointed out that the 2nd op amp was misconfigured.